# Lubuntu 18.04 Autostart Firefox doesnt work

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, autostart

I have a strange problem and hope that you can help me.

I am using Lubuntu 18.04 and just want to start firefox after user-login.

So I tried it to put it in the lx-session autostart and with a desktop file.

Both have the same problem.
They are starting, when I start any program for the first time.

E.g.:
I start my computer and autologin the user. Then nothing happens. When I click e.g. on "Terminal" it takes a few seconds for the first time, and then the terminal opens and then immediatly firefox from the autostart pops up.
Can I trigger this event with any method? 
It should autostart without doing anything, because it will be used in a display.

The other autostart functions (like start vino-server or unclutter for mouse hiding are working as expected).

Just firefox just wont start. Except I open any other program manually, then it comes up.

Currently I am using the lxsession autostart, so just the file:
`/home/username/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` with content

```
@firefox
```

Also tried without the @. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with XFCE on top. When I added Firefox for autostart, at first Firefox didn't find the chosen homepage. When I edited the           command for autostart to  `/usr/bin/firefox`, Firefox loaded the homepage   at  autostart. The problem seems to be that the default command in launcher is    `firefox %u`, so if also this command is edited to `/usr/bin/firefox`, this problem can be avoided in the future when you for some reason have removed Firefox from autostart and later put it back. See GUI:s:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this was of some help.